# Substitute input widget to control the output widget

Tags: qt, text, widget

It is normal in GUI, where we will set an Input Widget (Scrollbar, slider, lineedit, etc) and will be controlled/ displayed to the Output Widget (ProgressBar, LCD, Label)

Can I control the Output widget instead of using the Input widget, but I'm using a predefined text inside a textfile  (.txt) which will be loaded inside the Qt?

Example:

I open the notepad, type in '60' , save as ".txt" file and execute my program. As it launches, the progress bar inside the widget will move to "60", or the LCD will display "60".

Can anyone teach me how to do that?

Comment: Your question at the moment seems unclear. Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks frigatto, I'll try as best as I can.

Comment: You open the file, read the contents and adjust your GUI based on that. Which part is causing you trouble?

Comment: thanks @HiI'mFrogatto ,try my best 

In a usual scenario:
1. Execute the GUI program
1. We control the scrollbar (QScrollbar), slider (QHorizontalSlider), or any other widgets that allows the user to change the value.
2. The output widget (ProgressBar, LCDNumber,etc) will change accordingly to the value changed by the user.
My Scenario:
1. Open Notepad, type "55" , and save the text in ".txt"
2. Open Qt Creator, and execute GUI program , which has a progressbar/LCD inside.
3. The progress bar directly moves to value of "55"/ LCD displays "55".

How to do "My Scenario"? TQ

Comment: @thuga , the trouble is (or actually the request is) to automatically change the widget's value  once the GUI program launches.

Comment: That is not specific. You probably know how to change the value of a progress bar and your LCD. Is it the file reading? What exactly do you not know how to implement?

Comment: @thuga , Yes, I know how to change the value manually. but how about changing the value of a progress bar automatically based on the integer value inside a notepad file? 

lets say inside the notepad there is a text lines as below:

12, 400
40, 1300
23, 43

I save the file and once I open the qt creator, execute the program, and  once I hit the start button, the progress bar will go to 12% for 400 milliseconds, and then go to 40% for 1300 miliseconds, and finally 23% for 43 seconds before returning to 0%. 

hopefully I describe my problem clearly, and I do seek your kind assist, sir.

Comment: You can use [`QStateMachine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstatemachine.html) with `QTimer`.

Comment: thank you, @thuga . I will look for it. Very appreciate your assist :-)